# Undamped motion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find out $x$ and $x''$$=\frac {-k}{m}x$ where $\frac km = w^2$.
I have parameters
$$ \begin{cases}
\ x = 0 \\[2ex]
x' = V_0, & 
\end{cases}$$

I can understand that $$x' = \sqrt{V_0^2 - w^2  x^2}$$

or$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = \sqrt{V_0^2 - w^2  x^2}$$

but how is $$x = \frac{V_0}{w}sinwt $$
Which is what i want to find out.

This is a simple harmonic motion, undamped. Can someone explain to me how one would get to the final resusults

Comment: Who is $n$ ? Anyway, the harmonic oscillator is described with trigonometric functions. Put $x(t)=\frac{V_0}{\omega}\sin(\omega t)$ in your differential equation to see that it is a solution. Moreover, it fulfils the given initial values.

Comment: Sorry, that was an error, i will edit it out.

Comment: It's just a thing that bugged me. The book said "by further integration we get that $x= \frac{V0}{w}sinwt$
How does that process look like, i don't understand how one gets from x' to x with the given info.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to move from where you are now. One would be to go from your equation to $x'^2+w^2 x^2=V_0^2$, which says that $x$ and $x'$ together form an ellipse. Attempting to parametrize the ellipse gives the result. I would call this a "conservation of energy" method.

The other way is to separate variables. This is often written (slightly informally) like this:

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{V_0^2-w^2 x^2}} = \int dt.$$

The integral on the left becomes an inverse sine, after a substitution to adjust for constants. Solving for $x$ you get the result.

Also, this is more work than people usually do for this problem. The basic technique for solving linear DEs with constant coefficients analytically is to assume that the function takes the form $e^{\lambda t}$, where $\lambda$ (which might be complex) solves the characteristic equation. In this case the characteristic equation is $\lambda^2+w^2=0$, so the roots are $\pm w i$. Euler's formula then takes care of the rest.

Comment: I completely understand, and thank you very much. But don't Euler's formula also give a cosine by the negative roots. The formula is:
$e^ix = cos x + i sin x$

Comment: @allagillarbajs You get two complex exponentials, which (if the initial conditions are real) will combine to give the initial conditions, canceling the imaginary part in the process. For instance if all the constants are $1$ your solution is $c_1 e^{it} + c_2 e^{-it}$. The initial position condition gives $c_1+c_2=0$ and then the initial velocity condition identifies the constants. For instance if all the constants (including $V_0$) are $1$ you wind up with $\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}=\sin(t)$.

Comment: I might not have had to do as much work on this assignment. But i hate that something in my education should just be allowed to pass me by, or be labeled as "not 'that' important".

Comment: @allagillarbajs You're welcome. Also, I had some obvious typos. Corrections: If $w$ is $1$ then the solution is $c_1e^{it}+c_2e^{-it}$, irrespective of $V_0$ (or $x_0$, for that matter). If $x_0=0$ and $V_0=1$ then you get $\sin(t)$.